# Prove That Two Definitions Of Connected Sets Are Equivalent

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing

I have an exercise for which I want to prove that the two given definitions of disconnected sets are in fact equivalent.

**Def I:** A set $Y\subset X$ is disconnected if there are two non-empty subsets A and B of X such that:

1. $Y=A\cap B$
2. $A\cap\overline B=\overline A\cap B=\emptyset$

**Def II:** A set $Y\subset X$ is disconnected if there are non-empty open sets $U, V \subset X$ such that:

1. $Y\cap U\not=\emptyset$ and $Y\cap V\not=\emptyset$
2. $Y\cap U\cap V=\emptyset$
3. $Y=(Y\cap U)\cup(Y\cap V)$

So far I've gotten $\Rightarrow$ by letting $U=X\backslash\overline B$ and $V=X\backslash\overline A$ and then showing that U, V open and then $A\subset U, B\subset V$ and the rest follows from there.

However for $\Leftarrow$ I'm struggling. I let $A=Y\cap U$ and $B=Y\cap V$ which proves 1 but I can't seem to prove that $(Y\cap U)\cap(\overline{Y\cap V)}$, which is 2, is empty.

I've seen a few similar proofs but I haven't been able to follow them through. I want to show that $Y\cap U \subset X\backslash\overline{Y\cap V}$ because I can see how we conclude that 2. is true after that but I'm not sure of how to reason my way there or even how to see that it holds. Any help with the final steps or criticsm of my proof is appreciated, I'm still very new to both analysis and writing proofs.

Comment: $\ne$ is not transitive. I suppose you want $Y\cap U\ne\emptyset\ne Y\cap V$ as conditoin 1 in Def II

Comment: Oh, I did not know that. Thanks for pointing it out, I of course mean that both intersections are non-empty. I'll be more careful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

As the complement of $U$ is a closed set containing $B$, it also contains the smallest closed set containing $B$, i.e., $\overline B\subseteq X\setminus U$

Comment: I think I understand how to use this. Do you mind reading through what I've got and giving me criticism?

Comment: Wasn't supposed to post that.
(=>) Let A = Y n U and B = Y n V. Then Y = A U B which is precisely what we need for 1.
We now want to show that A n cl(B) is empty.
Since U open we have X\U closed and since A n B = Y n U n V is empty we have
Y n V subset of X\U but since the complement of U is a closed set containing B it also contains the smallest closed set containing B, that is cl(B). But then cl(B) is a subset of X\U => cl(B) n U-complement is not empty and thus cl(B) subset X\U => cl(B) n U = empty set.
Is that enough?